# Handle ui click on android - unity

Tags: android, canvas, unity-game-engine

I created an unity scene with some ui images. I try to handle click on them. My ui images are :

[image]

I attach box 2d collider to ui images. I activate `Allow Activation on Mobile Device` on `EventSystem` inspector.

[image]

Each ui images has a script file. The content of the files :

```
public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (eventData.clickCount == 1)
        {                
            model3d.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = newmaterial;
            eventData.clickCount = 0;
        }
    }
```

This code changes material only first click on ui images. It doesn't work after first click opetarion.

How can I handle click on ui images?

**SOLUTION**

I created ui->button. I set inspector->on Click properties. It works now.

Comment: this is completely wrong, zumma.  Simply click Add -> UI -> Button.  it will make a button for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I attach box 2d collider to ui images

You don't do that to UI Images. You only attach 2d collider to 2D Sprite which is not under the Canvas.

As long as `Raycast Target` is checked on each `Image` property and there is an EventSystem `GameObject` with `EventSystem` and `Standalone Input Module` scripts attached to it, that should work. So, remove 2d collider from all the Images under the `Canvas`.

Answer (score 0):

1-instead of UI image make a **button**
 
2-create the **script** you want to be called after click
3-attach your script to a game object (ie:camera)
4-in your button in the inspector there is a panel named **OnClick** click **+**
5-select the **gameobject** with the script(ie :camera) and in the next to the name of your script and select the **method** you want to call
6-each time you click on the object your script is called
and change your script to this

```
void changematerial()
{
            model3d.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = newmaterial;

}
```

Comment: I create button. Same problem exists. The material chnages after pressing  a few times.

Comment: you want to set the material to new material every time you click on the button?if that is what you want then what is the use of these lines         `if (eventData.clickCount == 1)`and             `eventData.clickCount = 0;` simply write             `model3d.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = newmaterial;`

Comment: Yes, I want to change material every click on the button. I remove clickcount control line, but the result is same. The material doesn't change every click operation. It is changed after several click operations.

Comment: maybe its collider is too small so it doesn't get clicked properly

Comment: ui button doesn't require a collider.

Comment: sorry , I meant the rect transform sale